# How to set CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH when invoking a console plugin action

Tags: plugin-development, console

I have an install where I've moved the `plugins/` directory outside of the `craft/` directory. I've set `CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH` in `index.php` and for web requests everything works fine.

Now I need to run a console command defined in a plugin. When I invoke the console from my shell, the default (incorrect) value for `CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH` is set and my plugin's console command is not available.

I've currently worked around this by wrapping `craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php`, setting the constant before requiring `yiic.php` like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../plugins").'/');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php');
```

Is there a better way to do this / am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you've done it the best way in Craft 2.

The upcoming Craft 3 treats console requests as more first class citizens like requests so it's not nearly as awkward using them.